# En Git como puedo subir todas las ramas de un proyecto a GitHub

Tags: git, github, ramas-git

Tengo un proyecto que he trabajado en local con Git el cual consta de varias ramas, cada una con un trabajo por separado el cual por el momento no puedo juntar en una sola rama master.

¿Existe alguna forma de subir todo de un paso a un repositorio de GitHub?

Comment: Si añades tu repositorio creado e inicializado puedes usar el comando `git push REMOTE --all`

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente sirva añadir un remote a tu repositorio local y hacer un push mirror, como indican en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266000/236345).

- crear un repo vacío en GitHub
- `git remote add github https://yourLogin@github.com/yourLogin/yourRepoName.git`
- `git push --mirror github`

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy sobre eso...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes subir todas las ramas a la vez usando:

```
git push --all origin
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches